# Set Table Separator Position

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have a table with two columns (It only has a single row).

But, I want to have the right column really near to the left column.
Whenever I try, the right column just aligns itself to the right.

Is there a way to set the separator's position, or, at least, set the right column's beginning position near the left column's end of text?

Example of my actual code:

```
<table style="width:400px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            First
        </td>

        <td>
            100
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Suggestions?

Comment: [Your code wil have "First" and "100" right next to eachother](http://cssdesk.com/9QUAT), barring non[-collapsed borders](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-collapse). Maybe your example isn't complete yet? Do you have a specific width on the table, perhaps?

Comment: @Jeroen Yes, it was just a rapid sketch, it had a fixed size. But the question has been succesfully answered. Thanks for your comment, in fact, if someone else comes and looks at that straight away could have thought I am dumb. Post edited, that's still a fast sketch anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try

```
table{ border-collapse: collapse; }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNNMJ/).

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what exactly do you want to achieve, you might want to take a look at [border-collapse CSS property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_border-collapse.asp). In your example, it should be set as:

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/G2ruz/)